# Convert string to entity - entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have created my entity framework objects/entities, and what I would like to do is create a dynamic query builder based on results from a table.

The table will have a column for the entity and properties on it.

What I want to do is loop through the records of this table, so each record will loop through and use DataProvider as the entity/table name and FieldName will be the property I want to access

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this? Or a better way to do dynamic SQL queries?

This is the code I currently have:

```
var record = db.TM_ACC_Account.IncludeAllEntities(db);
    
var query = await record.Where(item => item.acc_code == 306 && item.bck_id == 2).ToListAsync();  
    
    
var response = query.Select(a => Extensions.Projection(a, fieldMaps)).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the data stored in a database Table, View, or Stored Procedure result?

Comment: The data is stored in a table

Comment: In your Context you have `DbSet<Table> TableName { get; set; }` for the Table? And can you add your entity and context code to the post?

Comment: Yes I do. Then from there, I want to execute another query, dynamically, using the DataProvider field in the sreenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are going for would something like this work?

```
foreach (var res in response) 
{
   //query for get db context for res.DataProvider where query is on res.FieldName
   switch(res.DataProvider) 
   {
       case "TM_ACC_Account_Memo":
          // query TM_ACC_Account_Memo table on res.FieldName
          break;
       // other db entity cases
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```